# labeling graph edges

Tags: graph, divide-and-conquer

given an undirected graph, the question is to label its edges with three numbers for example two, zero, and one such that the sum of labels of all edges is minimized. Additionally, for every edge that is labeled with zero, there must exist a neighboring edge that is labeled with two. The task is to find the minimum sum of labels for the edges in the given graph.

Comment: " for every edge that is colored with 0, there must exist a neighboring edge that is colored with 2."  So the edge connecting a leaf vertex must be colored  1?

Comment: 1 or 2. maybe choosing 2 is better at some point. @ravenspoint

Comment: Yes.  See the algorithm I posted.  My comment referred ONLY to the edges connecting leaf nodes.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77793176/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/164956/755.  lease [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You got some feedback in the comments on CS.SE, and you provided some extra information in the comments there.  That is now deleted, so it is no longer visible.  I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide that extra information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for dynamic programming.  A straightforward algorithm can do the work.

Note that the edges that connect to leaf nodes MUST be colored 1.  If you color such an edge with 0 there is no other edge on the leaf vertex available to be colored 2 ( "*for every edge that is colored with 0, there must exist a neighboring edge that is colored with 2.*" )

- COLOR every edge with 1
- LOOP A

  - SET MAX = 0
  - SET MAXEdge = anything
  - LOOP E over edges with color 1

    - SET S = 0
    - LOOP e over edges to the vertices at each end of E

      - IF e connects to a leaf ( vertex with degree 1 )

        - CONTINUE
      - IF e is not colored 1

        - CONTINUE
      - SET S = S + 1
    - ENDLOOP e
    - IF S > MAX

      - SET MAX = S
      - SET MAXEdge = E
  - ENDLOOP E
  - IF MAX == 0

    - OUTPUT sum of all edge colors
    - STOP
  - COLOR MAXEdge with color 2
  - LOOP e over edges to the vertices at each end of MAXEdge

    - IF e color == 1

      - COLOR e with 0
- ENDLOOP A

Comment: i think its counting some edges more than once. 
can you please provide a code for it that actually works? every implementation i did results to a wrong output.

Comment: The algorithm is wrong. It outputs 4 for input values: (1 2) 

(2 3) 

(1 3). While it should be 2

Comment: no. sum of all edges i meant

Comment: It is necessary to ensure that each edge gets colored once only.  I have added a line to the algorithm to ensure this.